# Optimizing Array Memory Usage

Tags: ruby

I currently have a very large array of permutations, which is currently using a significant amount of RAM.  This is the current code I have which SHOULD:

Count all but the occurrences where more than one '1' exists  or three '2's exist in a row.

```
arr = [*1..3].repeated_permutation(30).to_a;

count = 0

arr.each do |x|
    if not x.join('').include? '222' and x.count(1) < 2
        count += 1
    end
end

print count
```

So basically this results in a 24,360 element array, each of which have 30 elements.

I've tried to run it through Terminal but it literally ate through 14GB of RAM, and didn't move for 15 minutes, so I'm not sure whether the process froze while attempting to access more RAM or if it was still computing.

My question being: is there a faster way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What about it needs clarified?  I would be happy to elaborate!

Comment: You need to edit your question to include an example. Show your desired output for, say, `arr = [[1,3,3,2,2], [4,1,1,1,2], [5,1,3,1,1]]`. Be sure to include a variable (here `arr`) whose value is the input array, so it can be referenced in answers and comments.

Comment: Revised question with more complete code and hopefully a clearer question

Comment: You said you have a very large array of permutations. That's incorrect. You have *created* that array, an array that is not needed. Delete `.to_a` and change `arr` to `enum`, for "enumerator". An enumerator is just a set of rules for generating a sequence. As such, it uses very little memory (here unrelated to the size of `[1,2,3]`). `enum.each do...` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what problem you try to solve. If your code is just an example for a more complex problem and you really need to check programatically every single permumation, then you might want to experiment with [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy):

```
[*1..3].repeated_permutation(30).lazy.each do ||
  # your condition
end
```

Or you might want to make the nested iteratior very explicit:

```
[1,2,3].each do |x1|
  [1,2,3].each do |x2|
    [1,2,3].each do |x3|
      # ...
        [1,2,3].each do |x30|
          permutation = [x1,x2,x3, ... , x30]
          # your condition
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it feels wrong to me to solve this kind of problem with Ruby enumerables at all. Let's have a look at your strings:

```
111111111111111111111111111111
111111111111111111111111111112
111111111111111111111111111113
111111111111111111111111111121
111111111111111111111111111122
111111111111111111111111111123
111111111111111111111111111131
...
333333333333333333333333333323
333333333333333333333333333331
333333333333333333333333333332
333333333333333333333333333333
```

I suggest to just use [enumerative combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_combinatorics). Just look at the patterns and analyse (or count) how often your condition can be `true`. For example there are 28 indexes in your string at which a `222` substring could be place, only 27 for the `2222` substring... If you place a substring how likely is it that there is no `1` in the other parts of the string?

I think your problem is a mathematics problem, not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

**NB** This is an incomplete answer, but I think the idea might give a push to the proper solution.

I can think of a following approach: let’s represent each permutation as *a value in ternary number base*, padded by zeroes:

```
1 = 000..00001
2 = 000..00002
3 = 000..00010
4 = 000..00011
5 = 000..00012
...
```

Now consider we restated the original task, treating zeroes as ones, ones as twos and twos as threes. So far so good.

The whole list of permutations would be represented by:

```
(1..3**30-1).map { |e| x = e.to_s(3).rjust(30, '0') }
```

Now we are to apply your conditions:

```
def do_calc permutation_count
(1..3**permutation_count-1).inject do |memo, e|
  x = e.to_s(3).rjust(permutation_count, '0')
  !x.include?('111') && x.count('0') < 2 ? memo + 1 : memo
end
```

Unfortunately, even for `permutation_count == 20` it takes more than 5 minutes to calculate, so probably some additional steps are required. I will be thinking of further optimization. Currently I hope this will give you a hint to find the good approach yourself.